# Phaser: How to fix the delay of the restart function, i am using window.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

```
var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 1900,
  height: 1000,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 300 },
      debug: false
    }
  },
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
  }
};
var main = document.getElementById("startBtn")
var gameOver
score = 0;
function start() {
  game = new Phaser.Game(config);
  main.innerHTML = ''
  score = 0;
}

function preload() {
  this.load.image('Background', 'assets/Background.jpg');
  this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
  this.load.image('coin', 'assets/coin.png');
  this.load.image('redCoin', 'assets/redCoin.png');
  this.load.spritesheet('monkey',
    'assets/monkey.png',
    { frameWidth: 600, frameHeight: 720 }
  );
}

var platforms;
var score = 0;
var scoreText;

function create() {
  this.add.image(500, 275, 'Background').setScale(3);
  this.w = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W)
  this.a = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A)
  this.s = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S)
  this.d = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D)
  platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

  platforms.create(200, 650, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(600, 400, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(1600, 650, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(750, 100, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(850, 750, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(100, 950, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(400, 950, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(700, 950, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(1000, 950, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(1300, 950, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(1600, 950, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(1900, 950, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(1800, 800, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(250, 250, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(1000, 500, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();
  platforms.create(1150, 220, 'ground').setScale(0.15).refreshBody();

  player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'monkey').setScale(0.075);
  this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
  player.setBounce(0.2);
  player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

  this.anims.create({
    key: 'left',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('monkey', { start: 0, end: 3 }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'turn',
    frames: [{ key: 'monkey', frame: 4 }],
    frameRate: 20
  });
  this.anims.create({
    key: 'right',
    frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('monkey', { start: 5, end: 8 }),
    frameRate: 10,
    repeat: -1
  });
  coins = this.physics.add.group({
    key: 'coin',
    repeat: 10,
    setXY: { x: 12, y: 0, stepX: 150 }
  });
  coins.children.iterate(function (child) {
    child.setBounceY(Phaser.Math.FloatBetween(0.4, 0.8));
    child.setScale(0.05)
  });
  this.physics.add.collider(coins, platforms);
  this.physics.add.overlap(player, coins, collectCoin, null, this);
  redCoins = this.physics.add.group();
  this.physics.add.collider(redCoins, platforms);
  this.physics.add.collider(player, redCoins, hitredCoin, null, this);

  scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '64px', fill: 'rgb(85, 1, 1)' });
}

function update() {
  cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

  if (cursors.left.isDown) {
    player.setVelocityX(-160);
    player.anims.play('left', true);
  }
  else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
    player.setVelocityX(160);
    player.anims.play('right', true);
  }
  else {
    player.setVelocityX(0);
    player.anims.play('turn');
  }

  if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
    player.setVelocityY(-330);
  }
}
function collectCoin(player, coin) {
  coin.disableBody(true, true);
  score += 1;
  scoreText.setText('Score: ' + score);
  if (coins.countActive(true) === 0) {
    coins.children.iterate(function (child) {

      child.enableBody(true, child.x, 0, true, true);

    });

    var x = (player.x < 400) ? Phaser.Math.Between(400, 800) : Phaser.Math.Between(0, 400);

    var redCoin = redCoins.create(x, 16, 'redCoin').setScale(0.05);
    redCoin.setBounce(1);
    redCoin.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    redCoin.setVelocity(Phaser.Math.Between(-200, 200), 20);

  }
}

function hitredCoin(player, redCoin) {
  this.physics.pause();
  player.setTint(0xff0000);
  player.anims.play('turn');
  gameOver = true;
  window.setTimeout(restart, 3000);
}
function restart () {
  this.scene.stop();
  this.scene.start();
}
```

This code is my game and it doesn't work because you can not respawn when you die, the delay doesn't work. I would like help fixing the time delay at the end of the hitredcoinfunction that calls the restart function. Please help me with this problem

it may be because I am using a delay thing from javascript, if so please tell me how to swap it out for the phaser version

pls help me with this, I really need my game to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `this` context is not set.
you can do this simply with the `bind` function. Here is the link to the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Just change the line to this:

```
window.setTimeout(restart.bind(this), 3000);
```

the `bind` function, passes an object/context *(in this case the phaser scene)* to the function, so that it can be referred to as `this`.

If you want to use the phaser `delayedCall` function you have to replace the line with (link to the documentation https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Time.Clock.html ):

```
 this.time.delayedCall(3000, restart, null, this);
```

> - the first parameter is the time in ms: **3000**
> - the second parameter is the function to call: **restart**
> - the third parameter are arguments, that should be passed to the passed function: **null**
> - the last parameter is the context, for the passed function: **this** *(the current scene)*

Comment: thanks that helped, relly appreciate it

Comment: Hello, Hello, Hello